# Scala: How to simply apply same method to all exceptions in catch block

Tags: scala

Consider following sample code

```
try{
    .....
}catch{
     case e1:Exception1 => { method1(..)}
     case e2:Exception2 => { method2(..)}
     case e3:Exception3 => { method3(..)}
}
```

Now if I'd like to run same method i.e. `methodGeneral()` to all exception (`e1`, `e2`, `e3`)

however how to avoid to apply the method in each block like below, but can achieve in one shot?

```
try{
    .....
}catch{
     case e1:Exception1 => { method1(..); methodGeneral();}
     case e2:Exception2 => { method2(..); methodGeneral();}
     case e3:Exception3 => { method3(..); methodGeneral();}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scala `Try` type offers a few more features than the basic `try..catch`. For example, you could do something like this.

```
import scala.util.Try

Try {
 . . .
}.recover{ excp:Throwable =>
  excp match {
     case e1:Exception1 => method1(..)
     case e2:Exception2 => method2(..)
     case e3:Exception3 => method3(..)
  }
  methodGeneral(excp)
}.get
```

This requires that the `.recover` code block returns the same type as the `Try` code block. If the return value is actually of no interest, such as `Unit` for example, then the `.get` can be omitted.

---

If you're really wedded to the old `try..catch` you might try something like this.

```
try {
  . . .
} catch {
  case excp: Throwable => 
    excp match {
      case e1:Exception1 => method1(..)
      case e2:Exception2 => method2(..)
      case e3:Exception3 => method3(..)
    }
    methodGeneral(excp)
}
```

It's still a good idea to ensure that the `try` block and `catch` block are type-compatible.

Comment: thanks that's what I am looking for. What if take a step further, to add exception as parameter in `methodGeneral(exception)` ?

Comment: thanks but I got `Missing parameter type: excp` from IDE

Comment: thanks, is there any way to work this out in the try .. match or catch method